# Error: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v6.0" were not found

Tags: c#, sdk, version, csproj, .net-core-2.1

I need help, because I can't solve this problem alone. I rebuild a C# project in VS 2019.

In first, I didn't have dotnet folder, so I downloaded it from here:

[Download .NET Core 2.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/2.1)

[Download .NET Core 2.1 - Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK55Z.png)

and now I get this error:

> The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v6.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.

This is the output from running `dotnet --info` on my machine:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version:   2.1.500
Commit:    b68b931422
Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.19045
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.500\
Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.6
  Commit:  3f4f8eebd8
.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

And this is the `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems> 
  </PropertyGroup>
```

What do I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Your target version is NET 6 in your cproj file, yet you download NET Core 2.1.5

Comment: Why are you installing .NET Core 2.1? It appears that you have not installed [.NET 6.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) (which your project is trying to use).

Comment: @GHDevOps Do I have to take a higher version for VS 2019? I'm afraid the code won't work for me. This is an old project.

Comment: Install VS 2022 so you can use at least NET 6 (long-term support). I think NET 3.1 is the latest version you can install with VS 2019.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Maybe i will do opposite? change the .csproj file to the current .NET version? i don't want to take a higher version.

Comment: If this project was originally a .net2.1 project, it should compile and run just fine with .net6.0, as the runtime is backwards compatible. net2.1 is so old that you won't find any support for it and barely anyone will still know its specifics.

Comment: @RinaBarak .NET Core 2.1 is not current and is no longer supported. .NET Core was renamed to just .NET. The current version of .NET is .NET 7.0. .NET 6.0 is the current LTS (Long Term Support) version. .NET 8.0 is in preview. Your project is set for .NET 6.0. Are you confusing .NET **Core** 2.1 with .NET **Standard** 2.1?